# NSException - dylib - Xcode error

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been following a tutorial and can't seem to manage to get it to run past a certain point, I've been over the original project with what feels like a ttothcomb but can't spot an mistake.

The exception isn't helping much and debug won't allow me to go any further into the code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

Post *post1 = [[Post alloc] initPost:@"Heading 1" content:@"Some content" location:@"Landaaan" rating:3 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"potatoBugThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"potatoBug.jpg"]];

Post *post2 = [[Post alloc] initPost:@"Heading 2" content:@"Some more content" location:@"Narwich" rating:5 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"centipedeThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"centipede.jpg"]];

Post *post3 = [[Post alloc] initPost:@"Heading 3" content:@"Some sdfsdfdf" location:@"Landaaan" rating:2 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wolfSpider.jpgThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wolfSpider.jpg"]];

Post *post4 = [[Post alloc] initPost:@"Heading 4" content:@"Some content" location:@"Landaaan" rating:4 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ladybugThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ladybug.jpg"]];


NSMutableArray *posts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:post1, post2, post3, post4, nil];

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController *masterController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
masterController.posts = posts;


// Override point for customization after application launch.
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
splitViewController.delegate = self;
return YES;
```

}

the error occurs at `masterController.posts = posts;`

with the stack trace  being:

```
       2015-11-21 01:08:18.323 unfoldIos[17542:359798] -[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aeebab0
2015-11-21 01:08:18.325 unfoldIos[17542:359798] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aeebab0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00a4da84 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0050ee02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00a56dd3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00994cdd ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x009948ae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   unfoldIos                           0x00037562 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x00fd97d4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 337
    7   UIKit                               0x00fdac02 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3863
    8   UIKit                               0x00fe22c7 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1971
    9   UIKit                               0x01006e4d __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3208 + 68
    10  UIKit                               0x00fdefb4 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 163
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x045f3ca4 __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    12  FrontBoardServices                  0x045f377b __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x046111a3 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x046115da -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x046108d6 FBSSerialQueueRunLoopSourceHandler + 33
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00967d1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0095d9ab __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0095cdc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0095c706 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0095c51b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  UIKit                               0x00fde854 -[UIApplication _run] + 540
    22  UIKit                               0x00fe41eb UIApplicationMain + 160
    23  unfoldIos                           0x00038a6a main + 138
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x032b0a21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

any help is hugely appreciated.

Edit:  I've deleted all of the yellow triangles from the controllers, same error remains.

Comment: There is some connection, object in your storyboard or *.nib that points to RWTMasterViewController. Since this class is not in your *.m or *.h file, when the storyboard loads it blows up

Comment: I hate non-storyboard coding. I almost exclusively use storyboard. Never the less try googling "topViewController unrecognized selector sent to instance" there are bunch of solutions that maybe relevant to your problem

Comment: @SamB, it's frustrating to say the least.  Not the best introduction to ios

Answer (score 0):

`[splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject]` this is not returning what you think it is. `NSLog(@"%@",[[splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] class])`. My guess is it logs MasterViewController.

Comment: any suggestions on how to remove it?  I've just set up a new project, followed it word for word and fails.  the only difference i can see is with the story board having more objects(such as the plait view) when the tutorial doesn't

Comment: Did you do what I suggested? What was the result? Try logging NSLog(@"%@",splitViewController.viewControllers);

Comment: I've just deleted the view from the story board and about to delete the project, can't be dealing with it anymore. thanks.